# Apply functions in a dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to apply multiple functions in a CSV document. I would like to have a first function that resends the data to other functions according to the value of your column

**Data (test.csv):**

> sentence,language
>
> .,fr
>
> .,en
>
> .,en
>
> .,it
>
> .,es
>
> .,fr
>
> .,fr
>
> .,fr
>
> .,es
>
> .,ge
>
> .,fr
>
> .,fr
>
> "Prezzi",it
>
> "it's not expensive",en
>
> "prix à baisser",fr
>
> "casi 50 euros la alfombra es cara",es
>
> "Prix,fr
>
> "PREZZI più bassi",it
>
> "Preis",ge
>
> "Precio",es
>
> "Price",en
>
> "es ist nicht teuer",fr

**Script:**

```
import string
import pandas as pd

def main(dataset):

    dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset, sep =',')

    text = dataset['sentence'] 
    language = dataset['language'] 

    for language in dataset:

        if language == 'fr':
            cleanText_FR()

        if language == 'es':
            cleanText_ES()

        if language == 'it':
            cleanText_IT()

        if language == 'en':
            cleanText_EN()

        if language == 'ge':
            cleanText_EN()

def cleanText_FR():

    text_lower = text.str.lower()

    punct = string.punctuation
    pattern = r"[{}]".format(punct)
    text_no_punct = text_lower.str.replace(pattern, ' ')

    text_no_blancks = text_no_punct.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
    text_no_blancks = text_no_blancks.str.rstrip()

    text_no_duplicate = text_no_blancks.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    text_cluster_random = text_no_small.sample(n=1000)

    text_list = text_cluster_random.tolist()


    return text_list

def cleanText_ES():

    text_lower = text.str.lower()

    punct = string.punctuation
    pattern = r"[{}]".format(punct)
    text_no_punct = text_lower.str.replace(pattern, ' ')

    text_no_blancks = text_no_punct.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
    text_no_blancks = text_no_blancks.str.rstrip()

    text_no_duplicate = text_no_blancks.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    text_cluster_random = text_no_small.sample(n=1000)

    text_list = text_cluster_random.tolist()

    return text_list

def cleanText_IT():

    text_lower = text.str.lower()

    punct = string.punctuation
    pattern = r"[{}]".format(punct)
    text_no_punct = text_lower.str.replace(pattern, ' ')

    text_no_blancks = text_no_punct.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
    text_no_blancks = text_no_blancks.str.rstrip()

    text_no_duplicate = text_no_blancks.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    text_cluster_random = text_no_small.sample(n=1000)

    text_list = text_cluster_random.tolist()

    return text_list

def cleanText_EN():

    text_lower = text.str.lower()

    punct = string.punctuation
    pattern = r"[{}]".format(punct)
    text_no_punct = text_lower.str.replace(pattern, ' ') 

    text_no_blancks = text_no_punct.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
    text_no_blancks = text_no_blancks.str.rstrip()

    text_no_duplicate = text_no_blancks.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    text_cluster_random = text_no_small.sample(n=1000)

    text_list = text_cluster_random.tolist()


    return text_list

def cleanText_GE():

    text_lower = text.str.lower()

    punct = string.punctuation
    pattern = r"[{}]".format(punct)
    text_no_punct = text_lower.str.replace(pattern, ' ')

    text_no_blancks = text_no_punct.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
    text_no_blancks = text_no_blancks.str.rstrip()

    text_no_duplicate = text_no_blancks.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

    text_cluster_random = text_no_small.sample(n=1000)

    text_list = text_cluster_random.tolist()

    return text_list

main("test.csv")
```

I did not have any results

> In [3]: runfile('/home/marin/Bureau/preprocess/preprocess.py', wdir='/home/marin/Bureau/preprocess')
>
> In [4]:

And I hoped I could have all my data treated as output.

**My question is not a duplicate! It's Python not R!**

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? It looks like you wrote a lot of code before checking to see if it was doing anything useful...

Comment: For example, you use `for language in dataset:` where `dataset` is a `pd.DataFrame`... have you checked to see what that does?

Comment: I'm not sure how this part works. I had thought of making **dataset = pd.read_csv (file, sep = ',')** but error: **NameError: name 'file' is not defined**

Comment: @Fozoro it's not R! It's Python!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your DataFrame with .iterrows() as follows:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset, sep =',')

for num, row in dataset.iterrows():
    text = row['sentence']
    language = row['language']
    #if statements and language clean method calls go here
```

Comment: Also you need to send text as parameter like `def cleanText_EN(text):`, and there are some basic mistakes in cleanText function definitons. You can fix them when you see the errors.